# How to make CITE tag entirely indented?

Tags: html, css, indentation

How to make CITE tag entirely indented? I have tested all of the

```css
padding-left: 200px;
margin-left: 200px;
text-indent: 200px;
```

and in all cases only first line was affected. How to shift right entire paragraph?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<cite>` elements are [phrase elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1); by default they are inline, not block.

You can set `display: block` on them to allow margin and padding to apply.